# Way to add condition on Running a Stage on Azure DevOps Multi stage YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am trying to implement a multi-stage pipeline in azure devops that is running everytime a push is committed all branches.

But, I would like to skip a certain stage in executing a pipeline stage using condition, given certain branches

Here is the initial script:

```
jobs:
- job: JOB A
  variables:
    protected_branches: master, main
  condition: containsValue(variables['protected_branches'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName'])
```

Seems this script is not working

Thank you!

Comment: I also added this approach but is returning an error when attempting to run pipeline

```
  - name: protected_branches
    type: object
      default:
        - main
        - master
  condition: containsValue('main', '${{ variables['protected_branches'] }}') 
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since variables in Azure DevOps pipelines can only be defined as strings, you should use `contains` instead of `containsValue`.

Here is a code sample where I trigger the pipeline from a branch named `test-pipeline`:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: Job_A
  variables:
    protected_branches: 'master, main'
  condition: contains(variables['protected_branches'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName'])
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Will only if source branch is: master or main"

- job: Job_B
  variables:
    protected_branches: 'test-pipeline'
  condition: contains(variables['protected_branches'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName'])
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Will only if source branch is: test-pipeline"
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Also note, the job name cannot contain a space. Job names can contain: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscores. You can use `displayName: ` to display a user friendly name in the interface.

Comment: No worries, please accept either mine or Andy's answer, whichever you think is most suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Scott is right, the variable is defined as strings, in this case we can use `contains` instead of `containsValue`.

However, we can use the `containsValue` expression to find a matching value in an object like below sample. See the expression [contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#contains) and [containsValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#containsvalue) for details.

> also added this approach but is returning an error when attempting to
> run pipeline `- name: protected_branches type: object default: - main - master condition: containsValue('main', '${{ variables['protected_branches'] }}')`

That's because you used the wrong syntax. The correct one should look like this:

```
parameters:
- name: protected_branches
  displayName: Source branch options
  type: object
  default:
    - master
    - main

jobs:
  - job: Job_B  
    condition: ${{ containsValue(parameters.protected_branches, variables['Build.SourceBranchName']) }}
    steps:
      - script: echo "Matching branch found -SourceBranchName - $(Build.SourceBranchName)"
```